# Which is more performant: jQuery.live(), or inline onevent attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, events, webkit

I'm building an HTML5 mobile app with a lots of event binding. Because it also has a large DOM that changes often due to data-binding, direct binding of events (**jQuery.bind** or **addEventListener**) probably isn't a good option. What are the tradeoffs between:

```
// jQuery.bind
$("div").live("click", fnName);

// Inline
<div onclick="fnName(this);"></div>
```

Though I'm most interested in the specific context of Mobile WebKit, I'd be interested to learn how other browsers fare as well.

Comment: How do you intend to measure performance, e.g. page load or response time?

Comment: @RobG: Response time and memory usage

Comment: For response time, inline will be way ahead, especially if there is a listener on every div. Might use a tad more memory, but the difference will be insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

`.delegate()` is said to be faster than `.live()`, and it might be an option for you.  You can read more [here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/).

Answer (score 2):

The .live() example will be much faster and use less memory than the onclick version.

Each time you do `onclick="fnName(this);"` you are creating a new function, and thousands of identical functions have a non-zero memory footprint. It will also take a little more time to create each div if you use `onclick`.

The difference between .live() and .delegate will probably be minor, but you should use .delegate() when you can.

Comment: A sub-question regarding .delegate (and also .bind): if the DOM node is ever deleted and recreated, will the attached event disappear with it? (I'm presuming so.) Both .live() and onevent get around this issue.

Comment: @evan - have you tested your claims? Inline handlers create a single function that is called when the related event reaches the element, they are not created every time. The difference is memory and load times would be negligable (if you can measure it at all). Event delegation can be done easily without jQuery or .live, making load times faster (100kb less code to load).